# How to install a connector on Mule Standalone?

Tags: mule, connector

I'm using Mule Standalone. From Mule Studio I'm using a connector I've installed, but since the standalone doesn't have it, it throws an error saying that it can't find the connector amqp:connector etc...

How can I install components in the Mule Standalone?

Comment: What version of Mule? Of the AMQP transport? Do you package the transport inside your application (did you add it to your POM?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be brought in your application `/lib` directory by Maven, as a dependency, when you build its package.

For the latest version of the AMQP transport, use:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-transport-amqp</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Oh... after re-checking the error, it says that found an error at the ampq:connector part. But if i run it from the mule studio, it doesn't happen, only from standalone.

Comment: Yeah had to add that dependency and also the ampq-client-3.1.3.jar one. Thanks David

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that your connector is in your projects class path before you export to standalone. You can do this automatically if you drag and drop your connector in a flow and save it.